# How to explore a ddrescue image manually / interactively?

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a ddrescue image containing data from a Btrfs partition whose first GBs were overwritten. Therefore, the filesystem cannot be mounted, so the files cannot be accessed through any filesystem as such — only as raw data.
I have already tried using TestDisk / PhotoRec to carve out data from this dd image, and I was able to recover many files.
Yet, what I now need is to able to explore this dd image more thoroughly, and interactively (as opposed to using some automated file recovery software).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a rough idea to get you started:

- Create an (empty) filesystem that’s as similar as possible
  to the one that was clobbered. 
  I guess making it the same size is probably fairly important;
  try to replicate as many other parameters
  as you can remember, recover, or reconstruct.
- Estimate how much of your filesystem got overwritten;
  let’s say that it was 3 GB.
- Make a copy of your image,
  and overwrite its first 3 GB with the first 3 GB of the empty filesystem.
- See what progress you can make on that hybrid image.

At first I was going to suggest that you use [debugfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html),
but then I recalled that it supports only ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems. 
But see if you can find tools that handle your filesystem type. 
Try searching for “computer forensic tools”.